# Getting more detail into Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have just been told that some of the projects I have to work on use Ember.js framework. It looks interesting and I want to gain more knowledge on it. I have also seen the official site but I think there's still a lack of proper tutorial for a beginner. Moreover, I just have a basic knowledge of Javascript. Where should I begin first? Javascript or head straight to Ember.js?

Edit: I would love to see suggestions from all Javascript developers and beginners how they started learning Javascript.

What I am planning to do is, read Eloquent Javascript and Head straight into Ember.js. If I am stuck on anything I can refer to SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to learn javascript first. `Ember.js` is a library for javascript, and thus is written in javascript, and thus is interfaced through javascript. Starting with `ember.js` is running before you can walk.

That said, here are a few resources to get you started:

**Javascript:**

[Mozilla Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide)

**Ember.js:**

[Adobe Tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/flame-on-a-beginners-guide-to-emberjs.html)

Comment: I'm not totally agree, as I began learning javascript with Ember. Reading the source code is usefull as I think it's written by experienced javascript developper. I admit I don't understand the overall, in particular the ember-metal code, but it's enough to develop an app or to help people here.

Comment: @sly7_7 So what do you suggest? In few weeks of time I may have to work on Ember.js.

Comment: @sly7_7 Oh, I sort of misread the question. I thought it said "I MUST have a basic knowledge of js", not "I JUST have..". If you already have a half decent understanding of javascript, you're probably fine to start learning ember. It isn't really a tough library to learn. I'd suggest running through the ember tutorial and consulting the javascript tutorial for things you don't quite understand

Comment: the "you"s in that post were directed at @user1601973

Comment: I have been through the adobe tutorial, any other links you can suggest?

Comment: usefull links around ember could be found here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/wiki

Comment: @user1601973. Hmm.. perhaps. [here](http://www.tuanleaded.com/blog/2012/04/getting-started-with-ember-js-the-missing-to-dos-manual/) is a pretty decent list of things you can do with ember and how to do them. I'd suggest trying to build yourself a basic app with what you know/learn from that, and then thinking to yourself, "Hmm.. I wonder what else I could do with this" -- then spend half an hour trying to figure it out yourself, and if you can't, post a detailed question here on SO. In my experience, that's pretty much the best way to learn *anything* programming-related.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt totally aggree with that :). Here are two apps https://github.com/elucid/ember-tunes and https://github.com/pangratz/dashboard/ well developped

Answer (score 14):

Personally, as @sl7_7, I began learning JS with Ember. So my answer should be Ember specific.

I learned them by reading the few tutorials, guide and examples I found, but essentially by reading the source code.

There are a lot of example available, but there are sometimes hard to find.
First, a list of useful blogs :

- https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/wiki
- http://emberjs.com/
- https://kippt.com/zaplitny/emberjs
- http://trek.github.com/ you **should** read it
- http://emberjs.tumblr.com/ (does not seem to be still updated?)
- http://codebrief.com/ - a blog written by Gordon L. Hempton
- http://www.cerebris.com/blog/ - written by Dan Gebhardt
- http://www.emberist.com/ - another really interesting blog for Ember, written by Peter Wagenet
- http://www.tuanleaded.com/blog/2012/04/getting-started-with-ember-js-the-missing-to-dos-manual/

And then, some examples :

- https://github.com/bazzel/ember-sample2 - a simple and recent Rails & Ember example written in Coffeescript. It contains a useful `Ember.Router` example
- https://github.com/elucid/ember-tunes - another simple Ember example
- https://github.com/ghempton/ember-router-example - an `Ember.Router` example
- https://github.com/pangratz/dashboard/ - a simple Github dashboard
- https://speakerdeck.com/bestie/tastebuds-radio-a-rapidly-developed-ember-dot-js-app - A speaker deck on a "rapidly developed app"

It is possible that I forgot many site, so just add a comment and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would do better learning Javascript first. You can head on to [Javascript.is(sexy)](http://javascriptissexy.com/) by Richard Bovell. He does a magnificent job of teaching JS basic and advanced concepts.